# How to use pipe operator in Mathematica?

Tags: functions

```
t = Table[i1 + i2 i3, {i1, 2}, {i2, 3}, {i3, 2}]
ArrayDepth[t]
```

How to use "pipe operator" in Mathematica Version 11.0?

In R, with library
[`magrittr`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org)
I can use a pipeline specification as below:

```
Table[i1 + i2 i3, {i1, 2}, {i2, 3}, {i3, 2}] %>% ArrayDepth[.]
```

How to use "pipeline specifications" in Mathematica?

Comment: You could use the postfix `//` operator, like `Table[i1 + i2 i3, {i1, 2}, {i2, 3}, {i3, 2}] // ArrayDepth` or `Table[i1 + i2 i3, {i1, 2}, {i2, 3}, {i3, 2}] // ArrayDepth[#] &`

Comment: "Pipeline operator" discussions at MSE can be found by the search [monadic programming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=monadic+programming).

Comment: Maybe `RightComposition`  ? Which is `/*`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps  you're looking for

```
Table[i1 + i2 i3, {i1, 2}, {i2, 3}, {i3, 2}] // ArrayDepth
(*3*)
```

Comment: If I need more pipe,can I use `Table[i1 + i2 i3, {i1, 2}, {i2, 3}, {i3, 2}] // ArrayDepth // function2`?

Comment: @kittygirl Yes, see `Table[i1 + i2 i3, {i1, 2}, {i2, 3}, {i3, 2}] // ArrayDepth // 
  N // Sqrt`.

Comment: Yes! What you call "pipe" is "PostFix" in Mathematica I think.

Answer (score 9):

In order to utilize the post fix operator `//` in WL in the way the R library
[`magrittr`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org)
implements/uses `%>%` several things have to be kept in mind.

- R's `magrittr` operator `%>%` :

  1. Assumes that the pipeline value is the first and only argument by default

     - Many of the `tidyverse` package functions rely heavily on this
  2. If a function needs only the first argument to be specified only the function name can be used
  3. Different argument location of the pipeline value can be specified with `.`
- In WL using the operator `//` :

  1. Often translating R `tidyverse` pipeline workflows in WL pipelines with `//` requires the argument location specification of the pipeline object
  2. If a function needs only one argument to be specified only the function name can be used
  3. The argument slot specification `#1` should be used (instead of `.` of R's `magrittr`.)

Clarification examples follow.

### Example 1

R-magrittr:

```r
 iris %>% nrow %>% runif
```

WL:

```
ExampleData[{"Statistics", "FisherIris"}] // Length // RandomReal[1, #1] &
```

### Example 2

R-magrittr:

```r
 iris %>% nrow %>% runif( n = 3, min = -10, max = .)
```

WL:

```
ExampleData[{"Statistics", "FisherIris"}] // Length //  RandomReal[{-10, #1}, 3] &
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `&` of `RandomReal[1, #1] &`?

Comment: @kittygirl `RandomReal[1,12]` generates 12 random numbers in the range [0,1]. It is equivalent to R's `runif(12)`.

Comment: What's the usage of `&`?

Comment: @kittygirl `RandomReal[1, #1]&` is a pure function specification, similar to `function(x) runif( n = x, min = 0, max = 1)` in R.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do this with Head? like `x %>% f(*args)` becomes `f(x, *args)` (in python-like syntax for arguments)

Comment: @qwr Yes. I have discussed in several blog posts and in a WTC-2017 presentation. See for example ["Monad code generation and extension"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2017/06/23/monad-code-generation-and-extension/).

Answer (score 8):

Note that in addition to the postfix notation `//`, you can also set up a pipeline of operators with `RightComposition` (`/*`) that can be re-used later. For example:

```
pipeline = Map[f] /* Apply[g] /* h
Range[5] // pipeline
Range[10] // pipeline

(* this also works, though it's maybe less intuitive *)
pipeline @ Range[5]
```

You can also use `Composition` (`@*`) if you prefer to read the other way around (i.e., the functions closest to the argument get applied first):

```
pipeline2 = h @* Apply[g] @* Map[f]
pipeline2 @ Range[5]
```

Comment: Nice observation/post. I would like point out that WL function composition is not the same  as the "pipelining" in R-tidyverse.